# Rules for a Hong-Kong based game

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, campaign-settings

I am considering running a Hong-Kong based Shadowrun campaign in the future, and even though I have found plenty of material regarding locations and NPCs (mainly in Runner Havens), I have yet to find rules and "crunch" for that specific setting.

One example would be that guns are more difficult to find in Hong-Kong, so a change in Availability would seem appropriate. Some advantages/flaws might have a different cost, some magic or summoning might work differently, and so on. I am not looking for ways to handle these specific points, but sources that would cover this kind of topics.

Basically, I am interested in some "crunch" to complete the "fluff". Is there any source out there that would mention **rules** for running Shadowrun in Hong-Kong? *(bonus points for additional cities)*

Comment: The closest thing to this in official sources, as far as I know, may date back to The Neo-Anarchist's Guide to North America, which did include rules along what you're looking for, albeit exclusively for North American destinations. Alas, I doubt it would be much use due to geographic and time differences, but it's worth a shot if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 5):

Hong-Kong is described in Runner Havens (50 pages), Shadows of Asia and Sixth World Almanach. The chapter about Wuxing in Corporate Download mention Hong-Kong.
I don't know rules about shadowrunning in Hong-Kong.